# Display Values in Dynamic Array - Run-time error '9' (Subscript out of Range)

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I have a dynamic array, when attempting to print it, I receive the error:

> Run-time error '9':
>
> Subscript out of Range

I have the following code:

```
Dim newTBArray As Variant
newTBArray = Range(newTBSheet.Cells(2, 1), newTBSheet.Cells(lastRow, 1)).Value

Debug.Print newTBArray(2)
```

Comment: your `newTBArray` is a 2-D array, if you want to print the entire second dimension, you need to loop through it, you can just use `newTBArray(2)` as if it was a single dimension array

Comment: Thanks, understood...

thus `Debug.Print newTBArray(2,1)` works,

Is there any way to input a `Range` into a single-dimension array?

Comment: Yes, use `Application.Transpose(Range...)`